# Making GWT Crawlable

Tags: java, ajax, gwt, servlets, web-crawler

Im having some problems with the GWT-AJAX crawlability. What Im currently doing is the following:

my website http://xyz.com has #! links like for example http://xyz.com/#!download/param
So the google bot would read it and ask my server for

http://xyz.com/?_escaped_fragment_=download/param

So what I've done is I built a servlet that produces the html content and returns it in the response. However, i have no idea where to map my servlet, what I mean is because the url that the google bot tries to fetch is xyz.com/?_escaped_Fragment_=download/param I dont know how to map the servlet in my web.xml

Answer (score 0):

You should rather use request filters than servlet mappings. Google even gives an example how to implement generic approach with HtmlUnit: http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/html-snapshot.html - see last section.

Comment: Ok I also tried filters but it's not actually working. In my web.xml I put the url mapping to /* and * but the filter is not being called on xyz.com?_escaped_fragment=.... I think it's because filters only respond when a servlet is called and there is no servlet mapped to xyz.com (the root url)